# Default of imfilter is correlation. How does deconvblind deconvolve?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, convolution

I just realized today that MATLAB's default convolving method for `imfilter` isn't convolution at all but correlation.

I'm wondering, though, how this changes the results by `deconvblind`?  It uses a maximum likelihood algorithm, but does it do so for an image convolved with correlation or for one that is convolved by convolution?

Please help me!  I can't find any information on this on the MathWorks site at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's more or less using convolution.  However, this is **not** done in the spatial domain, but in the frequency domain.  You can have a glimpse of what the method is doing by looking at the actual source code of `deconvblind` by using `open deconvblind` in your MATLAB command prompt.  Specifically, the relevant parts of what you want to know about is here towards the middle of the source:

```
% 2.c Determine next iteration image & apply positivity constraint
J{3} = J{2};
H = psf2otf(P{2},sizeI);
scale = real(ifftn(conj(H).*fw)) + sqrt(eps);
J{2} = max(Y.*real(ifftn(conj(H).*CC))./scale,0);
clear scale;
J{4} = [J{2}(:)-Y(:) J{4}(:,1)];
clear Y H;
```

The cell array `J` contains the deconvolved images and you can see that the images are obtained using the inverse FFT of the product of two images in the frequency domain, which is essentially convolution.

Convolution in the spatial domain is multiplication in frequency if you recall the properties of the Fourier Transform.  I won't go through the actual algorithm because you simply wanted to know whether it's convolution or correlation, but MathWorks does cite some relevant papers that the `deconvblind` algorithm uses.

See:

1. "Acceleration of iterative image restoration algorithms, by D.S.C. Biggs 
   and M. Andrews, Applied Optics, Vol. 36, No. 8, 1997.
2. "Deconvolutions of Hubble Space Telescope Images and Spectra", R.J. Hanisch, R.L. White, and R.L. Gilliland. in "Deconvolution of Images 
   and Spectra", Ed. P.A. Jansson, 2nd ed., Academic Press, CA, 1997.
3. "Light Microscopic Images Reconstructed by Maximum Likelihood
   Deconvolution", Timothy J. Holmes et al. in "Handbook of 
   Biological Confocal Microscopy", Ed. James B. Pawley, Plenum
   Press, New York, 1995

FWIW, correlation and convolution when filtering an image don't matter **if the convolution mask is symmetric**.  Convolution takes the kernel and rotates it by 180 degrees before the element-wise product and summation.  Correlation does not do this rotation, but the element-wise product and summation are the same.  If the kernel is symmetric, this means that rotating the mask 180 degrees will give you the same mask.  Should the mask not be so, you can specify the `'conv'` flag in `imfilter` to specify that you want to perform convolution.

Comment: Thanks so much!  Your note on symmetry helped a lot... it reminded me why what I'm doing works.  I guess I am still mostly confused as to why Matlab's imfilter uses correlation rather than convolution when their functions deconvolve by convolution.

Comment: @user1723196 - Correlation is slightly faster where you don't have to rotate the convolution matrix by 180 degrees.  You really don't see much difference in terms of the spatial version because the operations are the same.  BTW, if I have helped, please consider accepting my answer.  That can be done by clicking on the checkmark icon at the top of my post, to the left below the up and down voting arrows.  Good luck!